# Does enabling Wi-Fi drain more or less battery when tracking location?

Tags: android, ios, gps, wifi

I have a mobile app (iOS and Android) that pings the location ~ every 15 seconds and is used in urban areas.

From my understanding

- If Wi-Fi is disabled the app will use just GPS for location
- If Wi-Fi is enabled the app will either use a mixture of Wi-Fi and GPS or just Wi-Fi

Generally Wi-Fi on drains more battery however if you are tracking location then it might actually save battery since GPS is more battery intensive than Wi-Fi (I think!)

Does anyone have data if enabling (but not connecting to) Wi-Fi will be better or worse for battery life?

Comment: Can't you run the app for an hour or so in each mode and check the battery's status?

Comment: @TDG - Yes this is my fallback plan if I find no alternative.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to http://android.stackexchange.com/ since the question is not a programming one.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device/27742#27742

Comment: This is not just an android question - it applies to iOS too.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling WiFi should be good for battery life, but it depends entirely on how your application is coded. If you take a look at [Android's page on Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html), it says: 'GPS, Cell-ID, and Wi-Fi can each provide a clue to users location. Determining which to use and trust is a matter of trade-offs in accuracy, speed, and **battery-efficiency**.'

It is possible to get the location from just WiFi (yes, unconnected!):

```
netLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

but this may not be the most accurate solution. GPS uses a fair amount of power, but is obviously more accurate than WiFi, and searching for unconnected WiFi hotspots also takes power. In other words, this is a very complicated question.

All in all, the best solution (to avoid spending all your time coding this location stuff) is just to integrate Google Play services into your app. You can then specify the priority of finding the location (power or accuracy) and Google will sort it for you (check [this](https://www.toptal.com/android/android-developers-guide-to-google-location-services-api) out or the official google docs [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#PRIORITY_NO_POWER)).

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(15000);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;   
}
```

The other priorities are PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY, PRIORITY_LOW_POWER, PRIORITY_NO_POWER.

However, back to the question. If we look again at [Android's page on Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) and scroll down, it says: 'Depending on the environment where your application is used or the desired level of accuracy, you might choose to use only the Network Location Provider or only GPS, instead of both. Interacting with only one of the services reduces battery usage at a potential cost of accuracy.'

From this, we can draw that **using both WiFi and GPS gives a more accurate location than using just one**, but that using just one uses less power than using both. HOWEVER, this depends on the environment. Since your app is designed for use in URBAN environments, it is often harder to get GPS signals (due to buildings). But getting a location from WiFi alone does not work all of the time (even in urban environments). However, for your app, since it is used in URBAN environments, I believe that using **WiFi AND GPS will be the most power-efficient option** for you, because **sometimes GPS may not be available or will take a long time to connect (in urban environments)**. Remember, in urban environments people may lose GPS (e.g. they go into a store or into a very narrow alleyway). But if you have WiFi, you'll hopefully still be able to have their location. Another possible option to think about is trying to get their location using WiFi only at first, and then try GPS only if you can't get their location using WiFi. But this depends on how accurate you need their location. All in all, just leave it to Google (as shown above).

In answer to your question, it depends on how you're finding the user's location. I've suggested how to code your app, but if you want to leave it as it is, please post or comment the code you are using the find the user's location so that it can be determined which option is more efficient.

EDIT: I've seen that this is about iOS as well as Android. iOS provides much less control over how the location is determined. You just plug in the desired accuracy and Apple do the rest. Apple will determine the most power-efficient way of getting the location, and the same stuff that I've written above applies. Anyway, Apple will prompt users to turn on WiFi if it is disabled when getting the location, so trying to prevent use of WiFi for location on iOS is pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 0):

GPS power consumption is extremely high compared to WiFi. Most phone lasts less than 10 hours on GPS while with WiFi they can last more than day.

Comment: Do you have any data for this? All I could find was this from android which suggests that Wi-Fi takes more power when connected, but its not clear how much power it takes in 'location mode'.  Also the 'GPS searching' is an activity that takes a long time to begin with but once there is a GPS fix I imagine the battery cost is much lower.  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-device/27742#27742

Answer (score 0):

WiFi is not only for location or the internet, it has multiple uses,
if you are using older os than Marshmallow, you can't disable all functionality to use WiFi while it is on.

from Marshmallow you can enable it for the specific use like location only.
so it will consume less power than GPS.

while in the prior version, GPS is in winning condition in power consumption.
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/127571/116948

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any hardcore data on the subject, and doubt anybody will have any concrete numbers, but theoretically Wi-Fi will be far better than GPS only. The theory works something like the following: In order for a GPS to know where someone is at, it needs to receive information from 3 different objects at known locations and use triangulation to figure out its location from that, whereas wifi only needs to make one call, to the nearest internet repeater, which has a known location and known path. In order to assure accuracy this is often done multiple times with each location request. Thus the extra calls add up and Wifi will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use WiFi whenever you have access to a network because it uses less battery than GPS. (Shorter distance, lower power.) Turn WiFi off when you don't have access to a network, otherwise it will keep looking for a WiFi network it can use (which drains battery).